# Visual Studio with Browser Link: refresh browser when content in App_Data changes

Tags: visual-studio, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, browser-link

I use VS 2013 with Browser Link to test a site that loads its content from text files in *App_Data*. The files are actually Markdown files and edited outside of Visual Studio for convenience - I have a `grunt watch` task that copies the Markdown files from external location to *App_Data* whenever I change them.

I'd like to take this one step further - whenever there is a change to the Markdown file, I also want the browser to reload the page (which Browser Link can easily do). Is there a way to somehow configure Visual Studio / Browser Link to refresh the browser when file change happens inside App_Data? Or maybe there's some external API that I could call from my Grunt script to force Browser Link refresh?